# loading ogl texture using DEVIL

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, devil

here is my code

```
typedef struct Texture
{
    GLubyte *Data;
    GLuint  bpp;
    GLuint width, height;
    GLuint ID;
}Texture;

class TextureLoader
{
    public:
    TextureLoader()
    {
        ilInit();
        iluInit();
    }
    void load(ILenum FileType, const char *filename, Texture *texture)
    {
        ilLoad(FileType, filename);

        texture->width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
        texture->height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        texture->bpp = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL);

        texture->Data = ilGetData();
        ilEnable(IL_CONV_PAL);

        unsigned int type = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT);
        glGenTextures(1, &texture->ID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture->ID);
        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->bpp, texture->width,
            texture->height, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->Data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    }
}Loader;
```

and it doesn't seem to work.
There is segmentation fault after calling gluBuild2DMipmaps.
I can't understand what's a problem because code was mostly copy-pasted from an example(... 
This is a call of TextureLoader::load:

```
vector <Texture> bgtextures;
bgtextures.resize(1);
Loader.load(IL_JPG,"bgsnow.jpg",&bgtextures[0]);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `ilLoad()` can fail, why aren't you checking the return value?  Bet you're getting a `IL_COULD_NOT_OPEN_FILE` because your current working directory isn't what your program is assuming it is.

Comment: ilLoad() desn't fail
problem whith gluBuild2DMipmaps()

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return value of this:

`ilLoad(FileType, filename);`

By doing the following code:

```
if (ilLoad(FileType, filename) == IL_FALSE) {
    //Make it produce an error or something.
}
```

As genpfault suggested, you are likely passing in an incorrect filename.

Comment: if (ilLoad(FileType, filename) == IL_FALSE) {
cout << "ERROR IS HERE" << endl;
exit(1);
}
texture->width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
texture->height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
texture->bpp = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
texture->Data = ilGetData();
ilEnable(IL_CONV_PAL);
unsigned int type = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT);
glGenTextures(1, &texture->ID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture->ID);
cout << "1" <<endl;
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->bpp, textur->width,texture->height, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->Data);
cout << "2" <<endl;
my new code
same error